# How to normalize Google Sites page name using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

The Google Apps Platform protocol guides for Java and Python describe that the title of a page is normalized to a path using the following (incomplete) rule(s)*:

> Normalization is to trim + collapse whitespace to '-' and remove chars not matching a-z, A-Z, 0-9, -, _.

There is no such documentation that I can find for Google Apps Script and I'm unable to locate a helper function that achieves this - preferably in the same way that the Google Sites UI does.

My first attempt - which I know is not complete (it doesn't deal with how the Google Sites UI handles the beginning and ending of the string) looks like this:

```
str.trim().replace(/\s+/g, '-').replace(/[^a-z0-9_-]/ig, '-').toLowerCase();
```

The context in which I'm using this is that I've got a list of page titles and I'm trying to determine if the page already exists in a Site. Unfortunately, I cannot use the text representation to check.

For example, using the Google Sites "Create a new page UI", a page called "004.Policy Deployment (Hoshin Kanri)" will have a path "004-policy-deployment-hoshin-kanri".

In use, I'm trying to do check if a page exists, if it does, then do something, if it doesn't then do something else, like this:

```
if (mySite.getChildByName(myNewPagePath) != null) {
  // do something for pages that exist
} else {
  // do something for pages that don't exist
}
```

* https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/docs/1.0/developers_guide_protocol

Questions:

1. Is there an existing helper function that normalizes the title of a page?
2. Is there a better way to check if a page already exists?
3. Is there a way that I can check if a page exists by its end user title, rather than its path?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the list of children and loop through titles. Otherwise there isn't an existing function that does this although your regex looks good to me.

Comment: Unfortunately my regex behaviour is slightly different from the behaviour seen in the UI. Specifically, leading and trailing white-space combined with replaced characters does funky stuff. I tried tracing and breakpointing the UI and seeing if I could reverse engineer the actual code, but the level of obfuscation is beyond my attempts. Iterating through all pages is an option that I had not considered - pretty evil, but possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the search() method, passing in the un-normalized title, and then inspect the results to see if any of the pages have the expected title.